# ANOVA in python using pandas dataframe with statsmodels or scipy?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statsmodels, anova

I want to use the Pandas dataframe to breakdown the variance in one variable.

For example, if I have a column called 'Degrees', and I have this indexed for various dates, cities, and night vs. day, I want to find out what fraction of the variation in this series is coming from cross-sectional city variation, how much is coming from time series variation, and how much is coming from night vs. day.

In Stata I would use Fixed effects and look at the R^2.   Hopefully my question makes sense.

Basically, what I want to do, is find the ANOVA breakdown of "Degrees" by three other columns.

Comment: You'll want to look into scipy or statsmodels (I just added those tags, pending approval)

Comment: In a nutshell, statsmodels is analogous to the statistical parts of stata (whereas pandas is the data management part).

Comment: Anything more specific :) ?

Comment: The main ANOVA extension to the linear model (OLS) are explained here http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/interactions_anova.html  OLS Results have rsquared, anova_lm calculates the sum of squares or F tests for the effect of categorical variables.

Comment: By coincidence just came across the o'reilley book "think stats" which uses pandas and statsmodels.  Free online version here:  http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/html/index.html

Comment: There's a complete code example finishing with an ANOVA table and residuals at http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/anova.html.

Answer (score 32):

I set up a direct comparison to test them, found that their assumptions can [differ slightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755617/why-do-r-and-statsmodels-give-slightly-different-anova-results) , got a hint from a statistician, and here is an example of ANOVA on a pandas dataframe matching R's results:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols


# R code on R sample dataset

#> anova(with(ChickWeight, lm(weight ~ Time + Diet)))
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: weight
#           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)
#Time        1 2042344 2042344 1576.460 < 2.2e-16 ***
#Diet        3  129876   43292   33.417 < 2.2e-16 ***
#Residuals 573  742336    1296
#write.csv(file='ChickWeight.csv', x=ChickWeight, row.names=F)

cw = pd.read_csv('ChickWeight.csv')

cw_lm=ols('weight ~ Time + C(Diet)', data=cw).fit() #Specify C for Categorical
print(sm.stats.anova_lm(cw_lm, typ=2))
#                  sum_sq   df            F         PR(>F)
#C(Diet)    129876.056995    3    33.416570   6.473189e-20
#Time      2016357.148493    1  1556.400956  1.803038e-165
#Residual   742336.119560  573          NaN            NaN
```

Comment: But this is not ANOVA test. This is a linear model coefficients analysis.

Comment: @cphlewis, actually, an ANOVA test is nothing more than a linear model in which we have a continuous dependent variable and a categorical input.