# Confused about ANOVA in R

Tags: r, csv, lm, anova

I am new to R and statistics and am trying to do two-factor ANOVA on a dataset in csv file where values of each factor are in its own column. I was using

```
> mydata <- read.csv("myfile.csv")
> model = lm(result ~ factor1 * factor2, data=mydata)
```

As a check, I tried the ChickWeight data from R sample dataset.

```
> anova(with(ChickWeight, lm(weight ~ Time + Diet)))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: weight    
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)   
Time        1 2042344 2042344 1576.460 < 2.2e-16 *** 
Diet        3  129876   43292  > 33.417 < 2.2e-16 *** 
Residuals 573  742336    1296
> write.csv(file="ChickWeight.csv", x=ChickWeight, row.names=F)
> data = read.csv("ChickWeight.csv", header=T)
> anova(lm(weight ~ Time + Diet, data=data))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: weight
            Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
Time        1 2042344 2042344 1537.033 < 2.2e-16 ***
Diet        1  108177  108177   81.412 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals 575  764036    1329
```

Noticeably, degrees of freedom are lost for Diet column with the data read from csv into a dataframe. What am I missing here?

Comment: Compare the structure of the two datasets. The original has factors and ordered factors. I would assume for one structure, model needs more parameters which would result in the discrepancy between degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the clue from this post: [Why do R and statsmodels give slightly different ANOVA results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755617/why-do-r-and-statsmodels-give-slightly-different-anova-results)

When the data is being read from CSV file, the Diet column is becoming an ordinary numeric column, but for ANOVA it has to be a factor variable (I am still not clear why it is a separate class/kind in R and why it cannot take care of it automatically: inexact binary representation of floats? ).
So the solution was:

```
 > data$Diet = factor(data$Diet)
 > anova(lm("weight ~ Time + Diet", data=data))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: weight
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
Time        1 2042344 2042344 1576.460 < 2.2e-16 ***
Diet        3  129876   43292   33.417 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals 573  742336    1296
```